# Unable to select bootstrap modal buttons using tab buttons

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, accessibility

```
initialiseKeySelectModal() {
const modal_div = document.createElement("div");
this.setModalAttributes(
    modal_div, 
    {
        "class": "modal fade",
        "id": "keySelectModal",
        "tabindex": "-1",
        "role": "dialog",
        "aria-labelledby": "keySelectModalLabel",
        "aria-hidden": "true"
    }
);
modal_div.innerHTML = '<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="keySelectModalLabel">'
                + Joomla.getOptions('set_shorcut_text')
            + '</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" tabindex="-1"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="p-3">
                <p>'
                    + Joomla.getOptions('current_combination_text')
                    + ': <span id="currentKeyCombination"></span>
                </p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" id="current_KeyEvent" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="current_keyValue" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="current_hasControl" value="0" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="current_hasShift" value="0" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="current_hasAlt" value="0" />
                </div>
                <p>' 
                    + Joomla.getOptions('new_combination_text')
                    + ': <span id="newKeyCombination"></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" tabindex="-1">'
                + Joomla.getOptions('cancel_button_text')
            + '</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="saveKeyCombination" tabindex="-1">'
                + Joomla.getOptions('save_button_text')
            + '</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
document.body.appendChild(modal_div);
const keySelectModal = document.getElementById("keySelectModal");
Joomla.initialiseModal(keySelectModal);
keySelectModal.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDownEvent, false);
keySelectModal.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyCombinationkeyUpEvent, false);
const saveKeyCombination = document.getElementById("saveKeyCombination");
saveKeyCombination.addEventListener('click', this.handleSaveCombinationkeyUpEvent, false);
```

- This modal is used to capture the key combination changes
- This is the bootstrap modal which I'm using and I am not able to select modal buttons using keyboard tab button.
- I tried tabindex and focus to resolve.
- This modal include two buttons cancel and save changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove tabindex="-1" and insure that your keyUp and keyDown handlers do not return false or preventDefault() on the event.